# Creating a product for different companies with the same code

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

Im working on an product app in my company, This app will be delivered to more than one company with some difference and common things between each company app.

what is the best way to create my project ? should i use targets or what ? 
in android they can create multi module or multi project in the same project, how can we implement that in objective c ?

Comment: Do you want android or iOS?  Your tags are a mixture.

Comment: no i want it in iOS

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to know about Android Flavors, which provides functionality which you won't like.

You need to do some configurations and create some extra directory in your project, Then after you can create multiple copies of application some different changes.

You can learn it by android official Link:https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html

If any other query ask anytime.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but i want it in iOS